# Complexity of traversing 2 lists of difference sizes

Tags: time-complexity

What would be the complexity of comparing 2 different lists

```
For(object a: Array List) {
   For (object b: Array List) {
       If a==b then do something 
  }
}
```

I know when it is same list then it is O(n^2) but when it is different then what's the complexity

Thank you

Comment: `O(m*n)` `m` and `n` are the size of 1st and 2nd list respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the basics:

- **The complexity of traversing a single list of size N is O(N)** - everybody knows that
- **The complexity of traversing a single list of size M is O(M)** - the point I am trying to make here is that the letter inside O(...) does not matter

Now the answer becomes obvious:

- **The complexity of nesting O(M) operations inside O(N) loop is O(M×N)** - that's what leads to N<sup>2</sup> when M=N

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you

Comment: What if each array list is actually an array list of array list. The inner arraylist always contains 2 integers. Would it still be o(mxn) or will it be o (2mx2n)

Comment: @Snake Big-o pays no attention to constants, so O(2×N) is the same as O(4×N) or O(1000×N) for that matter - it's O(N).